# Does ejabberd "Community server" support Push notifications?

Tags: push-notification, xmpp, ejabberd

Ejabbered server has 3 versions - "Ejabberd Community Server", "Ejabberd SaaS" and "Ejabberd Business Edition". Only the first one is open source.

My question is whether the "Ejabberd Community Server" version supports push notifications?

In the following video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LToKLTf-N_E&feature=youtu.be&t=22m34s

at 6:40, it is mentioned that "Ejabberd SaaS" and "Ejabberd Business Edition" natively support push notifications. Does this mean that the "Ejabberd Community Server" version does not support it?

My use case is that I want to be able to send push notifications from a server to various client devices. The clients are running Android OS, however I cannot use Firebase cloud messaging (or Google cloud messaging) since the client devices do not have play services, which are required for both fcm and gcm

Comment: Hi, How did you solve this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The community version does not support push notifications. You need to implement the push service by yourself. For that, you can create a hook that triggers push notifications whenever the android client is offline. You can take a look at the following module that implements the same [here](https://github.com/adamvduke/mod_interact).

Comment: The new version of ejabberd community edition, i.e. version 17.08 supports push notification (xep 0357)

Comment: This is not true due to https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/3094#issuecomment-558602221